# Google maps works on phone NOT on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, emulation

Google mapview does not load the actual maps in the emulator, just the  grid. My overlays are displayed ok. sdk version 2.2. It works fine in a real phone. I use a debug key and trippel checked the manifest. It has been working in earlier projects. I just cant figure it out.. Any ideas, what to check?

Answer (score 2):

That's because your Google Maps API Key is bound to your retail key. In the Emulator you use debug-signed Apps, so you'll need a different Google Maps API key for the debug key you use to test it in the emulator

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your emulator has the google apis. I believe for Froyo, there are two different types of emulators you can create. An android 2.2 emulator, and an android 2.2 with google apis emulator.

Also, make sure you have signed your app with a [debug certificate](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#sign).

---

This may be obvious to you, but more info can be found [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html).

Comment: I think then his App would crash and not load an empty grid, if the Google Maps stuff was missing from his AVD

Comment: I think you're right. Then it would be that he hasn't signed his app correctly then, because it loads the map view, but it won't load the map content from google.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure your emulator thinks it has Internet access. This is indicated by two bars of signal strength -- if you see zero bars and an X where the 3G should go, then the emulator lacks Internet access. That probably means when the emulator started up, it could not detect the Internet.

Also, see if your emulator's Maps application works. If that fails, you know the problem is with your environment, not with your app.

Comment: Ok, thx! I installed the most recent update, which recently got available.. It solved the problem, but I'm still not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Please start the internet in your emulator it will start working.