# Application stops when setting map type

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am learning android google map development and I am following a tutorial on youtube, and it success to run this code and after that I insert a few code to display map marker on the map to get location but it getting "Unfortunately App has Stopped", it looks that the problem is when I execute `googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)` method.

This mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.mymap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                GoogleMap googleMap;
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-33.796923, 150.922433);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("My Spot")
            .snippet("This is my spot!")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this is manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- ** You need to replace the key below with your own key. **
     The example key below will not be accepted because it is not linked to the
     certificate which you will use to sign this application.
     See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
     for instructions on how to get your own key. -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyCvgeCVyyCQGLXxxmZ89NKKIB-VwMyzMqw"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mymap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is activity_main

```xml
<!-- This can go anywhere in your layout (see other demos for some examples). -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

this is my logcat

```
06-09 19:16:07.923: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1836): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:16:07.923: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1836): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:16:07.943: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1836): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:16:07.943: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1836): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:16:07.963: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1836): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:16:08.143: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1836): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:16:08.143: D/AndroidRuntime(1836): Shutting down VM
06-09 19:16:08.183: W/dalvikvm(1836): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught                     exception (group=0xb4da8908)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mymap/com.example.mymap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at com.example.mymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-09 19:16:08.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1836):     ... 11 more
06-09 19:16:08.493: D/dalvikvm(1836): GC_CONCURRENT freed 151K, 10% free 2582K/2844K, paused 28ms+3ms, total 170ms
06-09 19:17:11.352: E/Trace(1973): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-09 19:17:11.352: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:11.352: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:11.352: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:11.602: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:11.602: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:11.992: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1973): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:17:12.002: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1973): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:17:12.022: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1973): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:17:12.022: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1973): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:17:12.033: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1973): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:17:12.173: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1973): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:17:12.173: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1973): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:17:12.232: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.232: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.242: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.292: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.392: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.392: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.392: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.432: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.432: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.442: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.452: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.452: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.452: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.482: D/gralloc_goldfish(1973): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-09 19:17:12.622: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.653: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.772: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.772: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.812: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.812: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.862: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:12.862: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:32.752: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:32.752: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:32.784: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:32.822: W/Trace(1973): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:17:32.862: D/dalvikvm(1973): GC_CONCURRENT freed 140K, 9% free 2583K/2836K, paused 28ms+3ms, total 79ms
06-09 19:20:04.864: E/Trace(2082): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-09 19:20:04.864: W/Trace(2082): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:20:04.864: W/Trace(2082): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:20:04.864: W/Trace(2082): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:20:04.954: W/Trace(2082): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:20:04.964: W/Trace(2082): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:20:05.364: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2082): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:20:05.364: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2082): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:20:05.375: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2082): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:20:05.384: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2082): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:20:05.384: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2082): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:20:05.464: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2082): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:20:05.474: D/AndroidRuntime(2082): Shutting down VM
06-09 19:20:05.484: W/dalvikvm(2082): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4da8908)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mymap/com.example.mymap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at com.example.mymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-09 19:20:05.554: E/AndroidRuntime(2082):     ... 11 more
06-09 19:20:05.615: D/dalvikvm(2082): GC_CONCURRENT freed 164K, 10% free 2583K/2860K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 95ms
06-09 19:21:18.635: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:18.635: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:18.635: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:18.725: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:18.735: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.115: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2135): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:21:19.125: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2135): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:21:19.125: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2135): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:21:19.135: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2135): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:21:19.146: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2135): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:21:19.236: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2135): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:21:19.236: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2135): Google Play Store is missing.
06-09 19:21:19.395: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.395: I/Choreographer(2135): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-09 19:21:19.395: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.406: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.415: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.465: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.465: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.465: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.545: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.545: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.555: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.565: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.565: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.596: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.636: D/dalvikvm(2135): GC_CONCURRENT freed 144K, 9% free 2581K/2836K, paused 13ms+0ms, total 138ms
06-09 19:21:19.646: D/gralloc_goldfish(2135): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-09 19:21:19.745: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.755: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.875: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:19.875: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:20.015: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:20.015: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:20.046: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-09 19:21:20.046: W/Trace(2135): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps works on phone NOT on emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902058/google-maps-works-on-phone-not-on-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

If the logcat indicates that the line of error is:

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
```

The reason is probably because your device/emulator which you are testing this application on it, doesn't have `google-play-services` installed.

Another problem I see in your code is that you are missing those permissions:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.mymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: before I insert that code. my google map is display on my phone, but if I insert that function it appear this “Unfortunately App has Stopped”. I have try put those permissions too but the problem still same.